# What is Silverlight MediaStreamSource.AudioBufferLength measured in?

Tags: silverlight, audio

According to msdn, MediaStreamSource.AudioBufferLength "Gets or sets the length of the audio buffer". But what is that length? Milliseconds? Samples? Bytes? Anyone? Bueller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Milliseconds. See Pete Brown's posting [here](http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2009/07/19/Silverlight-Synthesizer-Source-Code-_1320_-MediaStreamSource-Raw-Sound.aspx).